# Calling an api in Azure AD B2C custom policy for postal address validation

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I've been tasked with setting up our company's Azure B2C environment. I've made a lot of progress and have had to use Custom Policies, as the default User Flows don't give us enough flexibility.

One of the requested features is to have a section in the SignUpOrSignIn policy, so that when a user signs up for the first time, we want to validate their postal address through an address validation api provided by a third party.

The way the api works, is first you pass in the post code, eg: AA11 1AA. The response will include a list of all the available addresses for the provided post code. You then call the api a second time with the unique id of the selected address, and this time the response breaks the address details out into each of its parts, eg: Line 1, Line 2, Town, County, Post Code.

So far I have an input for the postcode in the UI. I need to take this value and pass it to the api.

I now want to be able to display the list of addresses to the user in a DropdownSingleSelect list. Is it possible to dynamically populate these, rather than hard coding into the xml file? I also need to hide this list until it is populated.

Then after displaying the list to the user, they will select their address. This will then need to submit a second call to the api with the unique id.

Then the response needs to be populated into each of the address fields which are hidden up to this point. I also need to prevent the button at the bottom of the page to create the user from being active until this sequence is complete.

Are these actions possible? Or are the requirements too complex for B2C? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a dynamic dropdown box with javascript and some hidden fields rendered by B2C after getting the details from the REST API.

See this sample:
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/selectemail